# not getting results in django search but individual searching is working fine

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

my problem is when I'm adding simple functionality to individual search fields, it's working fine for single search fields, like after adding functionality for location field it's working as i wanted but after adding another functionality for another field it's not showing anything even the first field also not showing results, i think it's a very silly problem but i can't figure out that, please help me coders! (i've added html and views.py codes let me know guyz if you need anything else)

**html code**

```
<form action="{% url 'search-page' %}" method="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="location" id="location" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Location</option>
                                {% for key,value in location_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="types" id="types" class="form-control">
                                <option value="all-types">All Types</option>
                                {% for key,value in property_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
                                <option value="01">All City</option>
                                {% for key,value in city_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="status" id="all" class="form-control">
                                <option value="01">Status</option>
                                {% for key,value in status_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="bedroom" id="bedrooms" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Bedrooms</option>
                                {% for key,value in bedroom_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="bathroom" id="bathroom" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Bathroom">Bathroom</option>
                                {% for key,value in bathroom_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="price" id="bathroom" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Bathroom">Price</option>
                                {% for key,value in price_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <select name="size" id="bathroom" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Bathroom">Lot Size</option>
                                {% for key,value in lot_area_choices.items %}
                                <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="slider-range mb-15">
                                <div class="range-price text-white">Price [30000 - 150000]$</div>
                                <div class="slider-range-price ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                                    data-min="0" data-max="200000" data-unit="$" data-value-min="30000"
                                    data-value-max="150000" data-label-result="Price">
                                    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"></div>
                                    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
                                        tabindex="0"></span>
                                    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
                                        tabindex="0"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->
                        <!-- <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="slider-range mb-15">
                                <div class="range-size text-white">Size [9762 - 72063]sqFt</div>
                                <div data-min="0" data-max="98623" data-unit="sqFt"
                                    class="slider-range-size ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                                    data-value-min="9762" data-value-max="72063" data-label-result="Size">
                                    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"></div>
                                    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
                                        tabindex="0"></span>
                                    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
                                        tabindex="0"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn rehomes-search-btn">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
property_list = Property.objects.order_by('-date_added')

# Search_location
if 'location' in request.GET:
    location = request.GET['location']
    if location:
        property_list = property_list.filter(state__iexact=location)

# Search_types
if 'types' in request.GET:
    types = request.GET['types']
    if types:
        property_list = property_list.filter(property_types__iexact=types)

# Search_status
if 'bedroom' in request.GET:
    bedroom = request.GET['bedroom']
    if bedroom:
        property_list = property_list.filter(bedroom__lte=bedroom)

context = {
    'property_data': property_list,
    'location_choices': choices.location_choices,
    'property_choices': choices.property_choices,
    'city_choices': choices.city_choices,
    'status_choices': choices.status_choices,
    'bedroom_choices': choices.bedroom_choices,
    'bathroom_choices': choices.bathroom_choices,
    'price_choices': choices.price_choices,
    'lot_area_choices': choices.lot_area_choices
}
return render(request, 'property/search.html', context)
```

Comment: What is it showing if it's not showing the fields or results? Can you determine at which point in your template it's failing at? You can also install the django debug toolbar and see what the template's context is when it's being rendered.

Comment: actually it's not showing the results, as you can see there's functionality for 3 different search fields, if i comment out any of 2 fields functionality then it's working fine as i want,

Comment: the main thing is if i only add that search functionality for single field it is working, but when I add same functionality for another field it's not showing results, even though 1st field was showing the results but after adding another 1 that's not also showing the results, but all fields functionality are same, what do you think?

Comment: I'd install the Django Debug Toolbar and inspect the context being sent to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 'location' in request.GET:
    location = request.GET['location']
    if location:
        property_list = property_list.filter(state__iexact=location)

# Search_types
if 'types' in request.GET:
    types = request.GET['types']
    if types:
        property_list = property_list.filter(property_types__iexact=types)

# Search_status
if 'bedroom' in request.GET:
    bedroom = request.GET['bedroom']
    if bedroom:
        property_list = property_list.filter(bedroom__lte=bedroom)
```